# YAML not well formed

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Im trying to stop my RDS cluster using Lambda and Im using the python code shown below to target the clusters tags,
However when trying to create a CloudFormation stack, AWS is telling me that the YAML is not well formed.

For example it tells that Key = 'True'  is not well formed.
If I remove that bit of code it then tells me the next bit of code, client = boto3.client('rds') is also not well formed.

Ive put this code into an online python validator and it didnt report any issues.
Can anyone help with this? Thanks

```
Tag = 'AutoPower'
Key = 'True'


client = boto3.client('rds')
response = client.describe_db_cluster()

for resp in response['DBCluster']:
        db_cluster_arn = resp['DBClusterArn']

response = client.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceName=db_cluster_arn)
for tags in response['TagList']:
                if tags['Key'] == str(Key) and tags['Value'] == str(Tag):
                    status = resp['DBClusterStatus']
                    ClusterID = resp['DBClusterIdentifier']
                    print(InstanceID)

                if status == 'available':
                    print("shutting down %s " % ClusterID)
                client.stop_db_cluster(DBClusterIdentifier=ClusterID)

                # print ("Do something with it : %s" % db_instance_arn)
                elif status == 'stopped':
                    print("starting up %s " % ClusterID)
                client.start_db_cluster(DBClusterIdentifier=ClusterID)
                else:
                    print("The database is " + status + " status!")
```

Comment: Why is it being parsed as Yaml in the first place?

Comment: I suggest you edit the question title to include some more keywords such as lambda aws… that will improve the quality of the question and its reach.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, you are trying to create a lambda using cloudFormation which is going to perform some RDS activity. if you are having a "YAML" validation issue then please share the yaml/script file instead of python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely having issues due to indentation issues between CloudFormation YAML and the inline function code.  Here is an example of CloudFormation YAML that would use your code inline to create a function:

```
Resources:
  YourFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          Tag = 'AutoPower'
          Key = 'True'

          client = boto3.client('rds')
          response = client.describe_db_cluster()

          for resp in response['DBCluster']:
              db_cluster_arn = resp['DBClusterArn']

          response = client.list_tags_for_resource(ResourceName=db_cluster_arn)
          for tags in response['TagList']:
              if tags['Key'] == str(Key) and tags['Value'] == str(Tag):
                  status = resp['DBClusterStatus']
                  ClusterID = resp['DBClusterIdentifier']
                  print(InstanceID)
    
              if status == 'available':
                  print("shutting down %s " % ClusterID)
              client.stop_db_cluster(DBClusterIdentifier=ClusterID)
    
              # print ("Do something with it : %s" % db_instance_arn)
              elif status == 'stopped':
                  print("starting up %s " % ClusterID)
              client.start_db_cluster(DBClusterIdentifier=ClusterID)
              else:
                  print("The database is " + status + " status!")

      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Role: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/YourRoleNameHere"
      Runtime: python3.9
      Description: This is an example of a function in CloudFormation
      FunctionName: Your_Function_Name
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 180
```

Comment: Good answer, but wanted to add for the original user- this will NOT work as is because your python doesn't fulfill the lambda contract. For this to work with this yaml you would need to define a function called `lambda_handler` that accepts two arguments, which is what lambda will import and execute when you trigger your function.